# Disabled username in question

Tags: support

I've seen about three posts between SE and Workplace where the username of the poster is greyed out/plain text. Please what does this indicate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This means that the user does not exist on The Workplace.

This probably happened because the question was migrated here and the user who asked the question did not have a linked Workplace account.

If the username is an anonymous username (such as *user01234*), then it can be because the user was deleted.  In this case, I have seen cases where that number is the former user's site user ID.

Comment: Recently deleted users show up as "user6167" etc too, I don't think they show up as "anonymous" unless a specific post was anonymized (separated from an existing user's account)

Comment: @rarity, so bug then?

Comment: @kolossus they might have just asked for their account to be deleted. Happens surprisingly often.

Comment: @Rarity, you're right, but I was typing on my phone and didn't elaborate.  Thanks for making that clear.

Answer (score 3):

While Nick is correct that migrated posts may contain greyed out usernames for users who do not exist on the Workplace SE, there is currently a post by a user where there is no migration message. There appears to be no evidence that the post came from somewhere else from what I can tell.

[How to deal with a colleague who doesn't want to collaborate?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/8806/how-to-deal-with-a-colleague-who-doesnt-want-to-collaborate)

I also recall this reported as a bug elsewhere, as someone else on another Stack Exchange site reported seeing a greyed out username on a new post that *had not been migrated*.

Comment: +1, the man's right

Comment: The devil's in the details.

Comment: I happened to notice that post minutes after it was posted, the username was greyed out. There is one valid way this could have happened, the user deleted their account right after they posted the question. That's something that at some point we discussed here on Meta as a way to post (completely) anonymously, and it might just be exactly what happened. Or, it's a bug.